# Is there are any way of saving the input field values to the DOM Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i making a reminder app with jquery . i'm getting the values from the input fields and displaying the value under the input fields .But Every Single time i refresh the page , those values disappears . is there are any way that we can store values .

[image]

MY HTML

```
   <form id="form">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="getReminder"/>
                        <p class="text-center">
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                        </p>
                    </form>
```

MY JAVASCRIPT

```
 (function(){

var input           = $('#getReminder').attr('maxlength','30');
var checkboxSuccess = $('#checkboxSuccess');
var allFinished     = $('#allFinished');
$this               = $(this);

$( "form" ).submit(function() {
    if(input.val() == ""){
       input.addClass('warning').attr('placeholder','Please set the reminder').addClass('warning-red');
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
        input.removeClass('warning');
        $('<label>' +
            '<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSuccess" value="option1">' +
                 input.val().toUpperCase() +
                    '</label><br/>').appendTo('.checkbox');
                     event.preventDefault();

        return true;
    }

});

})();
```

Comment: Try to store it to browser local storage.

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Answer (score 0):

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/mbff6Lnj/

```
//Check Web Storage support
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
    input.val(localStorage.getItem("textValue"));// get Value from storage
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}

// And for set value 
localStorage.setItem("textValue", input.val());
```

Even you can use WebSql Also see this example .https://jsfiddle.net/Trae/76srLbwr/